# How I can translate the Magento2 admin theme in Arabic

Tags: magento2

I want translate a Magento 2 theme for a Magento 2 admin view.

How do I translate Magento 2 admin in Arabic language in RTL?

Comment: Please review this : https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Admin-Panel-not-take-translation/td-p/34850

Answer (score 0):

To translate the names and phrases in Magento 2, there are some steps that needs to be completed.

1. Generate a dictionary of your instance using the translation dictionary tool(1).
2. Translate the terms.
3. If desired, package your translations in a language package(2).

---

(1) https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict

(2) https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-pack